# Init-method from properties

Tags: spring

I would like to declare a bean for which init-method is not a constant value, but depends on a property:

```
<bean id="XXX" class="YYY" init-method="${some.property}"/>
```

I have a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean already configured, but unfortunately spring tries to call method named ${some.property} instead of the property value.

What should I configure in order to spring call the method pointer by some.property value?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure if Spring does support this but as an alternative you could read the property in the init method and dispatch accordingly in the code.

Comment: This is 2018, nobody should be using Spring XML anymore. Use `@Configuration`  classes and select the init method programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need to include the following bean and put the path to the properties file in the location property:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean" id="appConfig">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:appConfig.properties"></property>
</bean>
```

Let's suppose your properties file contains the following entry:

```
init_method = test
```

Then, by using your own code snippet, you should refer to aforementioned property in this way:

```
<bean id="XXX" class="YYY" init-method="#{appConfig['init_method ']}"/>
```

The appConfig must match bean's id declared on the first snippet